# ag-grid: How to sort set-filter values after translation while keeping the raw (untranslated) filter values

Tags: ag-grid

I have a problem using ag-grid and set filters.

- The **values** of the set-filter are a list of enums (strings) received from the backend
- We **translate** these enum values to different languages using **valueFormatter**
- Now we want the set filter to be **sorted according to the translated texts**

Here is a snapshot of our filter params:

```
filterParams: {
   values: this.filterValuesFromBackend,
   valueFormatter: (params: ValueFormatterParams) => this.translate(params.value)
}
```

As far as I can see **sorting is done using unformatted values** (enum values) and value formatting (here: translation) happens afterwards.

Important: Our table is a server side table where we use the filters in database queries.
Just using already translated texts as filter set values is no solution: We need the raw enum values from the set filter for database filtering afterwards.

Our current workaround ist to use a comparator which processes many additional translations just for sorting:

```
filterParams: {
   ...
   comparator: (a: string, b: string) => {
               const textA = this.translate(a);
               const textB = this.translate(b);
               return textA.localeCompare(textB);
   }
},
```

Here is a simple example:

- **Filter values**: bike, car, bus
- Frontend display translated and sorted values:

  - in Englisch: **bike, bus, car** (alphabetic order)
  - in German: **Auto, Bus, Fahrrad** (alphabetic order, English: car, bus, bike)
  - in French: **bus, vélo, voiture** (alphabetic order, English: bus, bike, car)
- **Backend received** "red", "green" and "blue" for database filtering

Do I miss something? Is using valueFormatte correct for translation tasks?

Comment: I am also encountering this exact problem in a React application with `ag-grid 28.2.0` (enterprise) and a server-side row model with a set filter. Great product but lamentable documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue.

For this particular case, I just tried to switch this column from valueFormatter to valueGetter and it seems to do the trick.

I don't need the raw data in my case so I'm good.  If you do need it, I suppose you could get away with a second hidden column with raw data.